# Python iterate between two datetime objects

Tags: python, date, datetime

How can I iterate between two `datetime.date` objects in Python?

For example, if I have two dates:

```
date1 = datetime.date(2024, 1, 10)
date2 = datetime.date(2024, 1, 20)
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
while date1 < date2:
    # do something
    date1 += 1 # days
```

How can I increment a `datetime.date` object by `1` day? There doesn't appear to be a way to manipulate a `date` object like that in Python?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a `datetime.date` object does not contain functions to manipulate it directly, it can be manipulated with an auxillary type - the `datetime.timedelta` type.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

date1 = date(2024, 1, 10)
date2 = date(2024, 1, 20)

current_date = date1

while current_date <= date2:
    print(current_date)
    current_date += timedelta(days=1)
```

Some other languages will provide ways of modifying a date object using a function like `increment_by_days(1)`, Python does not.

Comment: Indeed. This is noted in the documentation under *"Supported operations:"* https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects

Answer (score -1):

Hii the datetime module has a timedelta, which can be used to increment the current date by 1 day or even months.

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.date(2024, 1, 10)
date2 = datetime.date(2024, 1, 20)

threshold = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

while date1 < date2:
    # your operations
    date1 += threshold
```

Refer the official document: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects for more details.